# boost::asio async operations handler not called

Tags: c++, boost-asio

i would like to use a very similar pattern to the boost::asio example [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/timeouts/async_tcp_client.cpp), so i first ran the example on windows 10 running boost 1.71.0, and it executed properly. Dropped the unchanged client code in my project with main() replaced by:

[EDIT]

```
boost::asio::io_context io_context;
auto c = std::make_unique<test_async::tcp_client>(io_context);

work_guard_ = std::make_unique<work_guard_type>(io_context.get_executor());

worker_result_ = std::async(std::launch::async, [&]() {
    io_context.run();
    });

io_context.post([&]() { c->start(argv[1], argv[2]) });

 ...

// at end of program
work_guard_.reset();
worker_result_.wait();
```

and the async_handlers were not called. hmmm...

My question is: what could be going on to cause the tcp_client code to not work properly when used in my application, but it works fine in the example demo?

When trying to figure out why this wasn't working in my app, I replaced the async_connect with blocking connect, async_write with blocking write, and it worked. So, synchronous calls work, but async calls don't.

Not clear what's the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, pilot error.  The code worked, but it was called from a member function in a templated class. Put the code in the header file and it works. Feeling a bit silly right about now.
Thanks @sehe for a good answer

Answer (score 1):

Async operations run on the execution context.

The original code runs the execution context:

```
c.start(r.resolve(argv[1], argv[2]));

io_context.run();
```

You ***`stop()`*** it instead:

```
io_context.post([&]() { c->start(argv[1], argv[2]) });

 ...

io_context.stop();
work_guard_.reset();
worker_result_.wait();
```

The simplest thing you can do is remove the stop(), or put it at the end (where it will be redundant because `io_context.run()` by definition already returned when `worker_result_.wait()` returns.

Demo: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d71bb341292b76a)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

using boost::asio::steady_timer;
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using std::placeholders::_1;
using std::placeholders::_2;

//
// This class manages socket timeouts by applying the concept of a deadline.
// Some asynchronous operations are given deadlines by which they must complete.
// Deadlines are enforced by an "actor" that persists for the lifetime of the
// client object:
//
//  +----------------+
//  |                |
//  | check_deadline |<---+
//  |                |    |
//  +----------------+    | async_wait()
//              |         |
//              +---------+
//
// If the deadline actor determines that the deadline has expired, the socket
// is closed and any outstanding operations are consequently cancelled.
//
// Connection establishment involves trying each endpoint in turn until a
// connection is successful, or the available endpoints are exhausted. If the
// deadline actor closes the socket, the connect actor is woken up and moves to
// the next endpoint.
//
//  +---------------+
//  |               |
//  | start_connect |<---+
//  |               |    |
//  +---------------+    |
//           |           |
//  async_-  |    +----------------+
// connect() |    |                |
//           +--->| handle_connect |
//                |                |
//                +----------------+
//                          :
// Once a connection is     :
// made, the connect        :
// actor forks in two -     :
//                          :
// an actor for reading     :       and an actor for
// inbound messages:        :       sending heartbeats:
//                          :
//  +------------+          :          +-------------+
//  |            |<- - - - -+- - - - ->|             |
//  | start_read |                     | start_write |<---+
//  |            |<---+                |             |    |
//  +------------+    |                +-------------+    | async_wait()
//          |         |                        |          |
//  async_- |    +-------------+       async_- |    +--------------+
//   read_- |    |             |       write() |    |              |
//  until() +--->| handle_read |               +--->| handle_write |
//               |             |                    |              |
//               +-------------+                    +--------------+
//
// The input actor reads messages from the socket, where messages are delimited
// by the newline character. The deadline for a complete message is 30 seconds.
//
// The heartbeat actor sends a heartbeat (a message that consists of a single
// newline character) every 10 seconds. In this example, no deadline is applied
// to message sending.
//
namespace test_async {

    class tcp_client {
      public:
        tcp_client(boost::asio::io_context& io_context)
            : socket_(io_context)
            , deadline_(io_context)
            , heartbeat_timer_(io_context) {}

        // Called by the user of the client class to initiate the connection
        // process. The endpoints will have been obtained using a tcp::resolver.
        void start(std::string host, std::string service) {
            std::cerr << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
            tcp::resolver r(socket_.get_executor());
            endpoints_ = r.resolve(host, service);
            // Start the connect actor.
            start_connect(endpoints_.begin());

            // Start the deadline actor. You will note that we're not setting
            // any particular deadline here. Instead, the connect and input
            // actors will update the deadline prior to each asynchronous
            // operation.
            deadline_.async_wait(std::bind(&tcp_client::check_deadline, this));
        }

        // This function terminates all the actors to shut down the connection.
        // It may be called by the user of the client class, or by the class
        // itself in response to graceful termination or an unrecoverable error.
        void stop() {
            stopped_ = true;
            boost::system::error_code ignored_error;
            socket_.close(ignored_error);
            deadline_.cancel();
            heartbeat_timer_.cancel();
        }

      private:
        void
        start_connect(tcp::resolver::results_type::iterator endpoint_iter) {
            if (endpoint_iter != endpoints_.end()) {
                std::cout << "Trying " << endpoint_iter->endpoint() << "...\n";

                // Set a deadline for the connect operation.
                deadline_.expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(60));

                // Start the asynchronous connect operation.
                socket_.async_connect(endpoint_iter->endpoint(),
                                      std::bind(&tcp_client::handle_connect,
                                                this, _1, endpoint_iter));
            } else {
                // There are no more endpoints to try. Shut down the client.
                stop();
            }
        }

        void
        handle_connect(const boost::system::error_code&      error,
                       tcp::resolver::results_type::iterator endpoint_iter) {
            if (stopped_)
                return;

            // The async_connect() function automatically opens the socket at
            // the start of the asynchronous operation. If the socket is closed
            // at this time then the timeout handler must have run first.
            if (!socket_.is_open()) {
                std::cout << "Connect timed out\n";

                // Try the next available endpoint.
                start_connect(++endpoint_iter);
            }

            // Check if the connect operation failed before the deadline
            // expired.
            else if (error) {
                std::cout << "Connect error: " << error.message() << "\n";

                // We need to close the socket used in the previous connection
                // attempt before starting a new one.
                socket_.close();

                // Try the next available endpoint.
                start_connect(++endpoint_iter);
            }

            // Otherwise we have successfully established a connection.
            else {
                std::cout << "Connected to " << endpoint_iter->endpoint()
                          << "\n";

                // Start the input actor.
                start_read();

                // Start the heartbeat actor.
                start_write();
            }
        }

        void start_read() {
            // Set a deadline for the read operation.
            deadline_.expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));

            // Start an asynchronous operation to read a newline-delimited
            // message.
            boost::asio::async_read_until(
                socket_, boost::asio::dynamic_buffer(input_buffer_), '\n',
                std::bind(&tcp_client::handle_read, this, _1, _2));
        }

        void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error,
                         std::size_t                      n) {
            if (stopped_)
                return;

            if (!error) {
                // Extract the newline-delimited message from the buffer.
                std::string line(input_buffer_.substr(0, n - 1));
                input_buffer_.erase(0, n);

                // Empty messages are heartbeats and so ignored.
                if (!line.empty()) {
                    std::cout << "Received: " << line << "\n";
                }

                start_read();
            } else {
                std::cout << "Error on receive: " << error.message() << "\n";

                stop();
            }
        }

        void start_write() {
            if (stopped_)
                return;

            // Start an asynchronous operation to send a heartbeat message.
            boost::asio::async_write(
                socket_, boost::asio::buffer("\n", 1),
                std::bind(&tcp_client::handle_write, this, _1));
        }

        void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error) {
            if (stopped_)
                return;

            if (!error) {
                // Wait 10 seconds before sending the next heartbeat.
                heartbeat_timer_.expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(10));
                heartbeat_timer_.async_wait(
                    std::bind(&tcp_client::start_write, this));
            } else {
                std::cout << "Error on heartbeat: " << error.message() << "\n";

                stop();
            }
        }

        void check_deadline() {
            if (stopped_)
                return;

            // Check whether the deadline has passed. We compare the deadline
            // against the current time since a new asynchronous operation may
            // have moved the deadline before this actor had a chance to run.
            if (deadline_.expiry() <= steady_timer::clock_type::now()) {
                // The deadline has passed. The socket is closed so that any
                // outstanding asynchronous operations are cancelled.
                socket_.close();

                // There is no longer an active deadline. The expiry is set to
                // the maximum time point so that the actor takes no action
                // until a new deadline is set.
                deadline_.expires_at(steady_timer::time_point::max());
            }

            // Put the actor back to sleep.
            deadline_.async_wait(std::bind(&tcp_client::check_deadline, this));
        }

      private:
        bool                        stopped_ = false;
        tcp::resolver::results_type endpoints_;
        tcp::socket                 socket_;
        std::string                 input_buffer_;
        steady_timer                deadline_;
        steady_timer                heartbeat_timer_;
    };
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    if (argc != 3)
    {
      std::cerr << "Usage: client <host> <port>\n";
      return 1;
    }

#if OFFICIAL_BOOST_DOCUMENTIATION
    boost::asio::io_context io_context;
    test_async::tcp_client  c(io_context);

    c.start(argv[1], argv[2]);

    io_context.run();
#else
    boost::asio::io_context io_context;
    auto c = std::make_unique<test_async::tcp_client>(io_context);

    using work_guard_type = boost::asio::executor_work_guard<
        boost::asio::io_context::executor_type>;
    auto work_guard_ =
        std::make_unique<work_guard_type>(io_context.get_executor());

    auto worker_result_ = std::async(std::launch::async, [&]() {
        std::cerr << "Runner thread enter" << std::endl;
        io_context.run();
        std::cerr << "Runner thread exit" << std::endl;
    });

    io_context.post([&]() { c->start(argv[1], argv[2]); });

    //...

    work_guard_.reset();
    worker_result_.wait();
    io_context.stop();
#endif
  } catch (std::exception& e) {
      std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Prints

```
g++ -std=c++20 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp
(for a in {1..10}; do sleep 1; date; done) | nc -tlkp 4444 -w10 &
(sleep .5; ./a.out 127.0.0.1 4444)&
wait %1
kill %2
Runner thread enter
void test_async::tcp_client::start(std::string, std::string)

Trying 127.0.0.1:4444...
Connected to 127.0.0.1:4444
Received: Wed Sep 21 21:18:55 UTC 2022
Received: Wed Sep 21 21:18:56 UTC 2022
Received: Wed Sep 21 21:18:57 UTC 2022
Received: Wed Sep 21 21:18:58 UTC 2022
Received: Wed Sep 21 21:18:59 UTC 2022
Received: Wed Sep 21 21:19:00 UTC 2022
Received: Wed Sep 21 21:19:01 UTC 2022
Received: Wed Sep 21 21:19:02 UTC 2022
Received: Wed Sep 21 21:19:03 UTC 2022
Received: Wed Sep 21 21:19:04 UTC 2022
Error on receive: End of file
Runner thread exit
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the stop() issue, and apologies i wasn't clear in my explanation: the demo works fine on my system. However, when i drop the exact same code in my app, the async completion tokens never get called! that's what I'm not understanding

Comment: There's obviously some difference. It's not the exact same code. (Much like your _"Dropped the unchanged client code in my project with main() replaced by"_ wasn't actually the unmodified client code from [there](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/timeouts/async_tcp_client.cpp) either - I had to change the namespace, class name and change the constructor to take the resolver query arguments instead of results, imagine a `work_guard_type` etc.) Why make it a puzzle, only to tell me "my code is different" when we've solved the puzzle?

Comment: You're welcome to just show the actual code. No "...", no missing variables. Just minimal, self contained code (see sccee.org org https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)